# Attach an email from outlook to sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

with an custom button in "new list element" dialog in sharepoint I want to open the outlook inbox, choose an email and attach this mail to the current/new list entry.

How can I get access to outlook inbox to choose an email and copy or link this email as attachment to the list element!?

Please give me some hints or possible ways i can solve it. My favourite way is to solve this with c#.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you: http://spoutlookconnector.codeplex.com/

It can connect Outlook to SP so you can upload emails to SP list or document library. However, I am not sure, if you can invoke Outlook from SP.

This link could be at least a good starting point.